# React: fetching and showing or fetch and store, best practice

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I was looking for an answer to this question but I couldn't find it so I'll ask here:

What's the best practice when you fetch some data (for example a list of users) from an API in react and why?

1. Fetch the data and show it immediately in the component.
2. Fetch the data and store it in a global state (like with redux or hooks) and then show it.

and, how does this practice change when the data you are fetching is too big or you have a lot of different types of data you need to fetch (for example, users and products, and categories, and companies, and company branches, and brands, and stores, etc...) all in the same react application?

Comment: Usually, it's always good to store the data in a global state like a redux store, since that acts as the single source of truth. If in the future you build more components that use/depend on that data, then your life will become a lot easier if you already have that in redux.

Comment: The approach usually depends on the need.  
- If you are sure that the data you are fetching is / will be required / shared amongst other components, its best to save it in a global state like redux.